# How to enable Disabled third party sources from command line after upgrade

Tags: command-line, 16.04, apt, upgrade

I've upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04. As per the upgrade instruction, third party sources were disabled. After the upgrade, I cannot find a possible way to enable those third party sources using command line instead of **System Settings > Software & Updates > Other Software**.

I need to do it on command line because changing it via Settings requires password of a Super Privileged user (idk if that's the exact term). I can do all of the `sudo` and `sudo su` stuffs in command line with my current login, even though I've upgraded to 16.04 using `sudo do-release-upgrade` (Weird right..!? idk why sysadmin set up that restriction in first place).

Also another possible solution I think of is to reinstall those packages again which will re-enable those sources I guess.

Comment: it's the same password as you use for `sudo`...

Comment: @Zanna, Nope, I'm `admin`, but the super privileged requires password for `sysadmin`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I manage my sources manually from `cli` using a regular text editor like `vim` or `nano`.

The main `sources.list` is located here:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

and most third party sources are at:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

you can simply use a text editor to edit and enable them (uncomment):

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sample-sources.list
```

there should be lines like:

```
# deb http://ppa-url.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

you should uncomment them (remove `#`):

```
deb http://ppa-url.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

then the save the edited file and run `sudo apt update`.

Comment: @Ravexina, one small qn, what do i do with those `.distUpgrade` and `.save` files? Like this one `cwchien-gradle-trusty.list.distUpgrade`, `cwchien-gradle-trusty.list.save`..

Comment: @TheCoder They should be backup files, leave them be there in case you messed something up.